# Objective C: IKImageBrowserView show "Pages" templates like photo thumbnails

Tags: objective-c, ikimagebrowserview

I'm sort of new to cocoa.

I have managed to load images in IKImageBrowserView and everything is OK with images. What  I don't understand is how to load for example "Pages" templates so they would appear the way photos does - with a thumbnail showing content, but not "Pages" document icon, which happens now.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to leverage the [QuickLook framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to generate thumbnails in this situation.